# adding element at zoomed, D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

d3.js experts, what is the proper way to add an element at zoomed. the bug happens when this event happens:

- zoom the container by scrolling the mouse wheel
- click at the container to add the new circle
- unzoom
- the circle is not properly positioned

  jsfiddle.net/testoftheyearend/Lx9k72n6/170/

Comment: Works totally fine for me on Chrome / MacOS

Comment: @Shreshth
 try to zoom then add circle by clicking, then zoom out. the circle is misplaced :-(. the newly added circle is referenced to the unzoom container